# Proving the existence of minimal distance

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x \in X$. Let $Y$ be a compact subset of $X$. I want to show that there exists a point $\hat{y} \in Y$ such that:

$$d(x,\hat{y}) = \inf_{y\in Y}\{d(x,y)\}$$

not using the sequence characterization of the compactness of $Y$, but rather the topological defintion, that is every open subcover of $Y$ has a finite subcover.

My attempt was to derive a contradiction. Assume such a point $\hat{y}$ does not exits. Then consider the open cover of $Y$:

$$ U_n = \{z \in X| d(z,y) > \inf_{y \in Y} \{d(z,y)\}+\dfrac{1}{n}\}$$

Can we show that it has no finite subcover? Is there any other way to prove the statement using the topological defintion of compactness?

Comment: Your definition of the $U_n$ is unclear to me. When you write $d(z,y) > \dotsb$, what is the $y$ here? The point $z$ is given as the variable in the set-builder notation. The $y$ is taken care of in the expression $\inf_y d(z,y)$. But the other $y$ is unaccounted for.

Answer (score 1):

Your way looks like it works. There is another, slicker way to go that becomes more natural once you've learned a bit about compactness. You need a few facts

- The function $d(x,-) : X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by taking the distance to a fixed point $x$ is continuous.
- For any continuous function of topological spaces $f:A \to B$ and compact set $K \subset A$, the image $f(K) \subset B$ is compact.
- Any compact subset of a metric space is closed and bounded. In particular, a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ contains its maximum (and minimum).

Answer (score 0):

You've basically got it. As you noticed this is an open cover. Since $Y$ is compact, there is a finite subcover. Let it be $U_{n_1}, U_{n_2}, \cdots, U_{n_k}$. Then take the maximum of the $n_i$'s, call it $N$. So this means that every $z \in Y$ has the property that $d(z,x) > inf_{y \in Y}\{d(y,x)\} + 1/N$. But then this contradicts the definition of $inf_{y \in Y}\{d(x, y)\}$, i.e, it has to be at least $1/N$ bigger.